spring-cloud-dataflow 2.11.2 cronjob
is there anyway to set the timeZone for dataflow schedule cronJob?
I looked into the dataflow documentation and seem only have cronJobSpec options for backOffLimit and ttlSecondAfterFinished I couldnt find anything for timeZone

There is an open issue to add this feature.

It is not part of the standard API.
From Kubernetes specification:

CronJob limitations
Unsupported TimeZone specification
Specifying a timezone using CRON_TZ or TZ variables inside .spec.schedule is not officially supported (and never has been).


Starting with Kubernetes 1.29 if you try to set a schedule that includes TZ or CRON_TZ timezone specification, Kubernetes will fail to create the resource with a validation error. Updates to CronJobs already using TZ or CRON_TZ will continue to report a warning to the client.

